# Add \label of an environment to margin

Tags: cross-referencing, environments

Thank you in advance for your help with this somewhat niche question.

I am looking to make a command somewhere in my document preamble which makes it so that every environment (theorem/lemma/definition/corollary etc.) which is labelled (`\label{theorem-1}` for example), has the label itself automatically printed alongside it in the margin of the page (perhaps a boxed off `theorem-1`).

This would be really helpful for when I am trying to cross-reference documents I am writing.

Best,

M

Comment: `showkeys` package in the core latex/tools distribution

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realise this was such a simple solution, and strange that this didn't appear in my searching.

Comment: An alternative to @DavidCarlisle's `showkeys` package is the [`showlabels` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/showlabels). (They mention each other in the respective documentation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add   `\usepackage{showkeys}` to your preamble.